# property identifier not found on CLRegion

Tags: ios

I am having an array of CLregions and this is my code:

```
NSArray *_regionArray;
NSArray *_geofences_regions;

... in the ViewDidLoad
_geofences_regions = [self buildGeofenceData];
....


- (NSArray*) buildGeofenceData {
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"regions" ofType:@"plist"];
    _regionArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSMutableArray *geofences = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary *regionDict in _regionArray) {
        CLRegion *region = [self mapDictionaryToRegion:regionDict];
        [geofences addObject:region];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:geofences];
}

- (CLRegion*)mapDictionaryToRegion:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    NSString *title = [dictionary valueForKey:@"title"];

    CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees longitude =[[dictionary valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

    CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"radius"] doubleValue];


    return [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                                   radius:regionRadius
                                               identifier:title];
}
```

In the following code, `the property identifier is not found on object of type id`.

Why is that? Shouldn't `_geofences_regios[i]` return a CLRegion?

```
/*check for region*/
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [bestLocation coordinate];
                        for (int i=0; i<[_geofences_regions count]; i++) {
                            if ([_geofences_regions[i] containsCoordinate:coordinate]) {
                                [self.delegate locationManager:self regionEntered:_geofences_regions[i].identifier ];
```

}
                    }
                    /*end checking for region*/

Please answer on the above question, do not suggest me of using other delegate methods like didEnterRegion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the object returned by the array, by default is of type `id` that doesn´t have an `identifier` attribute, you can do a cast to avoid the error:

```
[self.delegate locationManager:self regionEntered:((CLRegion*)_geofences_regions[i]).identifier ];
```